# Refrescar los valores de un selectpicker bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap, select

hola bueno tengo un problema con los selectpicker tengo un formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el cual registra sin ningún problema,solamente que los selectpicker aparecen asi cuando se realiza un registro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es un ejemplo de como tengo un select

```
   <div class="mt-2">
                <select id="validationServer01" data-size="4"
                    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': !idNivelEstudios.valid && idNivelEstudios.touched}"
                    class="form-control form-control-sm selectpicker selectpicker1" data-live-search="true"
                    data-style="btn btn-outline-secondary " name="idNivelEstudios"
                    [(ngModel)]="educacion.idNivelEstudios" #idNivelEstudios="ngModel" required>
                    <option style="font-size: 11px;" selected="true" data-icon="mdi mdi-script"
                        [ngValue]='undefined' disabled="disabled">Nivel de estudios</option>
                    <option style="font-size: 11px;" selected="true" data-icon="mdi mdi-script"
                        *ngFor="let nivel of nivelEstudios" value={{nivel._id}}>
                        {{nivel.strNombre}}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Seleccione su nivel de estudios
                </div>
            </div>
```

y al momento de que obtengo la información del select en el ts en angular utilizo el refresh segun la documentacion de la misma

```
obtenerNivelEstudios() {

this.nivelesService.obtenerNiveles().then((niveles: any) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
  }, 0);

  let arrNiv = [];

  for (let niv of niveles.cont) {
    if (niv.blnActivo) {
      arrNiv.push(niv)
    }
  }
  this.nivelEstudios = arrNiv;
}).catch((err: any) => {

  Toast.fire({
    icon: 'error',
    title: err.err.msg
  });
  this.nivelEstudios = [];
});
```

}

tambien dicha linea de codigo la agrege en el ngOnInit y en la parte en donde se realiza el registro pero no funciono alguna recomendacion utilizo angular (: gracias

Comment: Hola, pudes intentar poner el refresh despues de la linea `this.nivelEstudios = arrNiv;`

Comment: Hola Oscar ya lo puse como me indicas pero no me funciono gracias por la respuesta (;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta ponerle **`title="Nivel de estudios"`** a tu etiqueta de **`select`** ya que en bootstrap select asi modificas el valor por default

```
<select title="Nivel de estudios" id="validationServer01" data-size="4"
[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': !idNivelEstudios.valid && 
idNivelEstudios.touched}" class="form-control form-control-sm selectpicker 
selectpicker1" data-live-search="true"
                data-style="btn btn-outline-secondary " 
name="idNivelEstudios"
                [(ngModel)]="educacion.idNivelEstudios" 
#idNivelEstudios="ngModel"  required>
```